# how to give css height a percentage of a different div (above original div)

Tags: css, html

I was wondering if its possible to make the height css value a percentage that uses the parent div (other divs).

In other words:

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <dic class=child>
        <div class=the_childs_child>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, say I have a `height` value of 50% on `the_childs_child`: originally, that would be 50% of the `child` div but could I make it 50% of the `wrapper` (or a different) div?

Comment: Are you looking for pure css way accomplishing this? If so you might be out of luck, js seems to me like the only way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No % is relative depending on the parents height. If you want to set it based on some other div you will need to get that div's height then set it accordingly using something like jQuery

Comment: Yeah I had that idea in mind. Was hoping for a CSS only way. Oh well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to get that element's height, and then set it using something like jQuery, but you can also use a css preprocessor such as [sass](http://sass-lang.com/). This makes it work, even if the user has javascript disabled.